# Write XML file with xinclude(xi:include) blocks with lxml

Tags: lxml, xinclude

I wish to automatically write a collective XML file using lxml and therefore I need to write "xi:include" something like:

```
...
<Time Type="Single" Value="2"/>
<xi:include href="elemData_2.xmf" xpointer="xpointer(//XDMF/Domain/Grid)"/>
<Time Type="Single" Value="3"/>
<xi:include href="elemData_3.xmf" xpointer="xpointer(//XDMF/Domain/Grid)"/>
<Time Type="Single" Value="4"/>
<xi:include href="elemData_4.xmf" xpointer="xpointer(//XDMF/Domain/Grid)"/>
...
```

It seems that XInclude() is only for parsing and trying to append a SubElement of name: 'xi:include' issues an error. So I would appreciate help for doing it. The code I use:

```
xdmfItem.append(etree.SubElement(Grid, "xiinclude", {'href': 'elemData_'+str(ii+1)+'.xmf', 'xpointer':'xpointer(//XDMF/Domain/Grid)' }))
```

The error:
    `ValueError: Invalid tag name u'xi:include'`

Thanks in advance 
Hisham

EDIT: (if I wait 8 hours I would probably not write the answer)

Thanks newtover, your pointer helped me find the solution:

```
xdmfItem.append(etree.SubElement(Grid, "{http://www.w3.org/2003/XInclude}include", {'href': 'elemData_'+str(ii+1)+'.xmf', 'xpointer':'xpointer(//XDMF/Domain/Grid)' }))
```

Comment: No. I really do not understand what you mean! Could you explain it to an XML illiterate?

Comment: Yes, I understood now. It is defined at the start of the XML file as: headerString = """<Xdmf xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2003/XInclude" Version="2.1"/>""" 
    Xdmf = etree.fromstring(headerString)